# What is the function of "set_crawler" and "from_crawler" in 'crawl.py' in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I can't understand those functions. If I inherit the `Spider` or `CrawlSpider`, should I override those functions. If not, then why?

```
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
    spider = super(CrawlSpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
    spider._follow_links = crawler.settings.getbool(
                                   'CRAWLSPIDER_FOLLOW_LINKS', True)
    return spider

def set_crawler(self, crawler):
    super(CrawlSpider, self).set_crawler(crawler)
    self._follow_links = crawler.settings.getbool(
                                 'CRAWLSPIDER_FOLLOW_LINKS', True)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Usually you don't need to override these functions, but it depends on what you want to do.

The `from_crawler` method (with the `@classmethod` decorator) is a [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) that will be used by Scrapy to instantiate the object  (spider, extension, middleware, etc) where you added it.

It's often used for getting a reference to the `crawler` object (that holds references to objects like `settings`, `stats`, etc) and then either pass it as arguments to the object being created or set attributes to it.

In the particular example you've pasted, it's being used to read the value from a `CRAWLSPIDER_FOLLOW_LINKS` setting and set it to a `_follow_links` attribute in the spider.

You can see [another simple example of usage of the from_crawler method in this extension](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/c9d7386a32aeb4bc7fe9654d194651eee1ede56c/scrapy/contrib/spiderstate.py#L7) that uses the `crawler` object to get the value of a setting and passing it as parameter to the extension and to connect some [signals](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html) to some methods.

The `set_crawler` method has been deprecated in the latest Scrapy versions and should be avoided.

#### Read more:

- [Core API and the Crawler object](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/api.html)
- [Writing your own Scrapy extension](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#writing-your-own-extension)
- [Scrapy Signals](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html)